# Can't update record in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My query returns me error, Please let me know what i'm doing wrong

```
$q="UPDATE from 'id' SET 'pass'='$pass1' where 'name'='$user1'";
```

Comment: We need more description about the ERRORS . Please state your problems in a proper way

Comment: i am facing this error 
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id'' at line 1"

Comment: If you submit `<input type="submit" name="sb" />` it's never go in `if(isset($_POST['sb']))` because `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` condition going false. This method of Login and Register is totally wrong.

Comment: so now what to do now @kupendra

Comment: you can separate `isset($_POST[])` for different `form` submission. Means all `if(isset)` condition is use separately. Not use `if(isset)` in other `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your sql is wrong:

```
$q="UPDATE from 'id' SET 'pass'='$pass1' where 'name'='$user1'";
```

it should be something like:

```
$q="UPDATE id SET 'pass'='$pass1' where 'name'='$user1'";
```

Comment: yes and what about the error in line one..You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id'' at line 1

Comment: id is you database name or table name.

Comment: table name, and one more thing i can't create account here.. please  modify

Comment: instead of $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'test'" or die(mysql_error()); use $sql = "SELECT * FROM test";

Comment: @mysql_select_db('your database not table') or die(mysql_error());

Comment: i follow your instructions.. login setup is done and working when something is wrong it move to first form but when something is wrong in second form it ends.. i need to go further another form.. how i can do that? 
@suchit